# HRESULT = 80004005 with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, reference, setup-project, hresult

I'm getting this error when building my project, and I can't fix it.
I have two solutions with the same setup projects referenced in both, and probably thus, the problem.

I googled, I look it up here in StackOverflow, and did all what people said that should be done: removing and readding references, and a long etcetera.

I will paste here my output hoping that someone can throw a little ray of hope on me, please..

thanks a lot everybody in advance.

Best,
Manuel.

```
------ Build started: Project: CPTUtils, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
CPTUtils -> D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\CPTUtils\bin\Debug\CPTUtils.dll
------ Build started: Project: CPT.Security, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
CPT.Security -> D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\Tools\CPT.Security\bin\Debug\CPT.Security.dll
------ Build started: Project: CPTTranslations, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
CPTTranslations -> D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\CPTTranslations\bin\Debug\CPTTranslations.dll
------ Build started: Project: CPTDB, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
CPTDB -> D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\CPTDB\bin\Debug\CPTDB.dll
------ Build started: Project: DBManagement, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
DBManagement -> D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\DBManagement\bin\Debug\DBManagement.dll
------ Build started: Project: DBMGTBaseExtensions, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
DBMGTBaseExtensions -> D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\DBMGTBaseExtensions\bin\Debug\DBMGTBaseExtensions.dll
------ Build started: Project: Exporter, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Exporter -> D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\Exporter\bin\Debug\Exporter.dll
copy "D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\Exporter\bin\Debug\Exporter.dll" "D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\bin\Debug\"
copy "D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\Exporter\bin\Debug\Exporter.pdb" "D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\bin\Debug\"
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
------ Build started: Project: DBMgtRevisioning, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
DBMgtRevisioning -> D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\DBMgtRevisioning\bin\Debug\DBMgtRevisioning.dll
------ Build started: Project: NetworkTools, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
NetworkTools -> D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\Tools\NetworkTools\bin\Debug\NetworkTools.dll
------ Build started: Project: DBInstaller, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
DBInstaller -> D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\DBInstaller\bin\Debug\DBInstaller.exe
------ Build started: Project: DCClasses, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
DCClasses -> D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DCClasses\DCClasses\bin\Debug\DCClasses.dll
------ Build started: Project: XMLReporter, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Consider app.config remapping of assembly "EnvDTE, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "7.0.3300.0" [] to Version "8.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\PublicAssemblies\EnvDTE.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.
XMLReporter -> D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\XMLReporter\bin\Debug\XMLReporter.exe
Done building project "XMLReporter.csproj".
------ Build started: Project: DuboCalc2.0, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning : The referenced project '..\..\DCClasses\DCClasses\DCClasses\DCClasses.csproj' does not exist.
Consider app.config remapping of assembly "CPT.Security, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d593bbb549999bfb" from Version "1.0.4314.17230" [D:\Projects\DataLayer\CPTDB\bin\Debug\CPT.Security.dll] to Version "1.0.4402.23887" [D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\Tools\CPT.Security\bin\Debug\CPT.Security.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /main:DuboCalc2._0.Program /reference:D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\Tools\CPT.Security\bin\Debug\CPT.Security.dll /reference:D:\Projects\DataLayer\CPTDB\bin\Debug\CPTDB.dll /reference:D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\CPTTranslations\bin\Debug\CPTTranslations.dll /reference:D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\CPTUtils\bin\Debug\CPTUtils.dll /reference:D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\DBInstaller\bin\Debug\DBInstaller.exe /reference:D:\Projects\DataLayer\DBManagement\bin\Debug\DBManagement.dll /reference:D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\DBMGTBaseExtensions\bin\Debug\DBMGTBaseExtensions.dll /reference:D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\DBMgtRevisioning\bin\Debug\DBMgtRevisioning.dll /reference:D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DCClasses\DCClasses\bin\Debug\DCClasses.dll /reference:D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\Exporter\bin\Debug\Exporter.dll /reference:..\dll\Infragistics2.Excel.v9.2.dll /reference:..\dll\Infragistics2.Shared.v9.2.dll /reference:..\dll\Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinChart.v9.2.dll /reference:..\dll\Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinDataSource.v9.2.dll /reference:..\dll\Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcelExport.v9.2.dll /reference:..\dll\Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v9.2.dll /reference:..\dll\Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinTabControl.v9.2.dll /reference:..\dll\Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinTree.v9.2.dll /reference:..\dll\Infragistics2.Win.v9.2.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll /reference:D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DataLayer\Tools\NetworkTools\bin\Debug\NetworkTools.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.configuration.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Deployment.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Design.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\XMLReporter\bin\Debug\XMLReporter.exe /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /nowin32manifest /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2.0.exe /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Forms.AxisAnalysisForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Forms.EnvironmentRatiosForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Forms.frmAbout.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Forms.frmData.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Forms.frmSplash.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Graph.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Forms.LibrarySelectionForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Forms.LibrarySelectionForProject.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Forms.LibrarySelectionForUpgrade.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Forms.MassBalanceForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.ProjectForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Forms.ProjectPropertiesForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Forms.ReportSelectionForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Forms.SearchResultsForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Forms.TotalOverviewForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Forms.UpdatePreviewForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.SearchForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.frm_AddMaterialProcess.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.OptionsForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.SimpleSearchForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.TypeEditor.ExtraPropertiedForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.UILongString.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Forms.VariantAnalysisForm.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.DuboCalcMain.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.Properties.Resources.resources /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.WinFormStrings.resources /resource:Resources\english.resources,DuboCalc2._0.Resources.english.resources /resource:Resources\DuboCalc2._0.i18n.resources,DuboCalc2._0.Resources.DuboCalc2._0.i18n.resources /resource:Entities.bmp,DuboCalc2._0.Entities.bmp /resource:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2.0.exe.licenses /target:winexe /win32icon:DC.ico DCHelp\HelpManager.cs Forms\AxisAnalysisForm.cs Forms\AxisAnalysisForm.Designer.cs Forms\EnvironmentRatiosForm.cs Forms\EnvironmentRatiosForm.Designer.cs Forms\frmAbout.cs Forms\frmAbout.Designer.cs Forms\frmData.cs Forms\frmData.Designer.cs Forms\frmSplash.cs Forms\frmSplash.Designer.cs Forms\Graph.cs Forms\Graph.Designer.cs Forms\LibrarySelectionForm.cs Forms\LibrarySelectionForm.Designer.cs Forms\LibrarySelectionForProject.cs Forms\LibrarySelectionForProject.Designer.cs Forms\LibrarySelectionForUpgrade.cs Forms\LibrarySelectionForUpgrade.Designer.cs Forms\MassBalanceForm.cs Forms\MassBalanceForm.Designer.cs Forms\ProjectPropertiesForm.cs Forms\ProjectPropertiesForm.Designer.cs Forms\ReportSelectionForm.cs Forms\ReportSelectionForm.Designer.cs Forms\SearchResultsForm.cs Forms\SearchResultsForm.Designer.cs Forms\TotalOverviewForm.cs Forms\TotalOverviewForm.Designer.cs Forms\UpdatePreviewForm.cs Forms\UpdatePreviewForm.Designer.cs HelperClasses\DuboCalcSettings.cs HelperClasses\ExcelExporter.cs HelperClasses\ItnterFaces.cs HelperClasses\JSONConverter.cs HelperClasses\ScreenGraber.cs HelperClasses\Utils.cs LibUpdate\LibraryUpdater.cs LibUpdate\ItemComparator.cs ProjectExplorer\GUIMaterial.cs ProjectExplorer\GUIProcess.cs Forms\SearchForm.cs Forms\SearchForm.Designer.cs Forms\DropDownTreeView.cs Forms\frm_AddMaterialProcess.cs Forms\frm_AddMaterialProcess.Designer.cs Forms\ProjectForm.cs Forms\ProjectForm.Designer.cs TypeEditor\CollectionEditor.cs TypeEditor\ExtraPropertiedForm.cs TypeEditor\ExtraPropertiedForm.Designer.cs TypeEditor\LongStringEditor.cs Forms\OptionsForm.cs Forms\OptionsForm.Designer.cs IconManager.cs Icons.cs ProjectExplorer\GUIItemMaterial.cs ProjectExplorer\GUIItemProcess.cs Forms\SimpleSearchForm.cs Forms\SimpleSearchForm.Designer.cs UILongString.cs WinFormStrings.nl-NL.Designer.cs I18n.cs ProjectExplorer\Element.cs Forms\VariantAnalysisForm.cs Forms\VariantAnalysisForm.Designer.cs ProjectExplorer\GUIItem.cs ProjectExplorer\Project.cs ProjectExplorer\XMLHelper.cs DuboCalcMain.cs DuboCalcMain.Designer.cs Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs Properties\Settings.Designer.cs ProjectExplorer\Variant.cs WinFormStrings.Designer.cs
D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\DuboCalc2.0\DuboCalcMain.cs(22,7): warning CS0105: The using directive for 'System.Data' appeared previously in this namespace
D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\DuboCalc2.0\Forms\DropDownTreeView.cs(48,15): warning CS0108: 'DuboCalc2._0.DropDownTreeView.Margin' hides inherited member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Margin'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll: (Related file)
D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\DuboCalc2.0\Forms\frm_AddMaterialProcess.Designer.cs(166,64): warning CS0108: 'DuboCalc2._0.frm_AddMaterialProcess.Name' hides inherited member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Name'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll: (Related file)
D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\DuboCalc2.0\Forms\ProjectForm.cs(2263,42): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\DuboCalc2.0\DuboCalcMain.cs(289,21): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\DuboCalc2.0\ProjectExplorer\Project.cs(668,20): warning CS0219: The variable 'toc_content' is assigned but its value is never used
D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\DuboCalc2.0\I18n.cs(28,30): warning CS0168: The variable 'e' is declared but never used
D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\DuboCalc2.0\Forms\ProjectForm.cs(49,22): warning CS0414: The field 'DuboCalc2._0.ProjectForm.m_multiselect' is assigned but its value is never used
D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\DuboCalc2.0\Forms\SearchForm.cs(28,22): warning CS0414: The field 'DuboCalc2._0.SearchForm.rename' is assigned but its value is never used

Compile complete -- 0 errors, 9 warnings
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\AL.exe /culture:nl-NL /out:obj\Debug\nl-NL\DuboCalc2.0.resources.dll /template:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2.0.exe /embed:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2._0.WinFormStrings.nl-NL.resources
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\AL.exe /culture:en-US /out:obj\Debug\en-US\DuboCalc2.0.resources.dll /template:obj\Debug\DuboCalc2.0.exe /embed:Resources\english.en-US.resources,DuboCalc2._0.Resources.english.en-US.resources
DuboCalc2.0 -> D:\Projects\DuboCalc\DuboCalc2.0\DuboCalc2.0\bin\Debug\DuboCalc2.0.exe
Done building project "DuboCalc2.0.csproj".
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'DuboCalcInstallNoSQL' ------ 
WARNING: File 'jit.js' should not be installed into a User's Profile folder because it may not be available to all users.
WARNING: File 'example1.js' should not be installed into a User's Profile folder because it may not be available to all users.
WARNING: File 'Spacetree.css' should not be installed into a User's Profile folder because it may not be available to all users.
WARNING: File 'DuboCalcOptions.xml' should not be installed into a User's Profile folder because it may not be available to all users.
WARNING: File 'base.css' should not be installed into a User's Profile folder because it may not be available to all users.
WARNING: File 'form.html' should not be installed into a User's Profile folder because it may not be available to all users.
WARNING: File 'excanvas.js' should not be installed into a User's Profile folder because it may not be available to all users.
WARNING: File 'jit-yc.js' should not be installed into a User's Profile folder because it may not be available to all users.
ERROR: Invalid or unspecified target for shortcut 'DuboCalc 2.1'
ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '80004005'
------ Pre-build validation for project 'DuboCalcInstallNoSQL' completed ------
------ Build started: Project: DuboCalcInstallNoSQL, Configuration: Debug ------
========== Build: 13 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: What type of project is DuboCalc2.0?  Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: @JaredPar it's a Windows Application and as far as I know, I don't have any extensions installed. How can I check for that?

Comment: if you're not aware of any then you almost certainly don't have any installed.  I hadn't ever encountered some of those errors and was surprised they'd come from a wnidows app

Comment: @JaredPar I was wondering if there was something incorrect in the output, since I have a warning `Consider app.config remapping of assembly "EnvDTE, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "7.0.3300.0" [] to Version "8.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\PublicAssemblies\EnvDTE.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.` or `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning : The referenced project '..\..\DCClasses\DCClasses\DCClasses\DCClasses.csproj' does not exist.`

Comment: That last error is bad.  As an experiment i'd try hard coding the full path to that project.

Comment: @JaredPar what's that? how do I do that?

Comment: open up the project file directly and hard code the full path to the project.

Comment: @JaredPar you mean this? `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets`

Comment: Crazy thought but "Invalid or unspecified target for shortcut 'DuboCalc 2.1'" Yet you seem to be building DuboCalc v2.0, (not v2.1).

Comment: @JaredPar I already fixed that one deleting one of the files that was suppose to install in the setup, but still the HRESULT error :(

Comment: That HRESULT is E_FAIL, also known as "unspecified error". Easily the least helpful error message in the history of the world; all you know is that something failed and the author of the code did not know why.  This is an extremely difficult error condition to debug. Good luck!

Comment: @EricLippert but I get the 80004005, not the E_FAIL; as I google it, E_FAIL gets return from a call to a COM component and I'm not using that.

Comment: @noloman "...EFAIL gets return from a call to a COM component". Yeah, I wouldn't trust that too much. Although there are supposed to be rules, developers can (and do) return whatever code they like. "80004005/Unspecified error" is frequently the return code from a caught exception.

Comment: @noloman: E_FAIL is the *name* of the error code 80004005, the same way that "twelve" is the name of the number 12. I assure you, you're getting E_FAIL and you are probably getting it from a COM component.

Comment: @EricLippert maybe, the problem is that all this was working PERFECTLY like a week ago; maybe I touched something (I don't remember having touched anything) and when I started VS, I got this nasty and ugly error here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this checking the whole project out again and starting from scratch.. took me a whole day, but I fixed it :)